# Javascript: div doesn't scroll to bottom of page.

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am using Node.js, 
I have this function which gets called on user entering the chat room.

```
function loadMessages(msg, pseudo, time){
    $("#chatEntries").append('<div class="messagesOLD">' +
    "<span class='msg_date'>"+dateFormat(time)+"</span><span class='msg_seperator'> | </span><span class='msg_name'>"+ pseudo + '</span> : ' + msg + '</div>');
    $("#chatEntries").scrollTop($("#chatEntries")[0].scrollHeight);
}
```

The first part of it gets called, so messages are loaded and added to chat window, while the 2nd part doesn't work, it just stays on top and doesn't scroll it to bottom.
There is no errors thrown or anything.

Comment: just a hunch, but you should probably be scrolling to `$('#chatEntires').offset().top + $("#chatEntries").height()`

Comment: that didn't work either